# node.js/random access with 1024KB

Tags: node.js, random-access

I use [random access](https://www.npmjs.org/package/random-access-file) package for node.js.

Everything works fine when I sending chunks with 100Kb size. But when I send chunks in size of 1024kb, I see that the random access package writes only the first chunk, and ignore the others.

This issue is known? How can I supports random access without this package?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug with that particular module.

However node does have a [built-in way](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) (the `position` parameter of `fs.read`/`fs.write`) of writing to/reading from specific offsets. You might try using that directly instead.

Comment: But the problem that I need to know the size of the file before, not?

Comment: If you write to a file position that is past the end of the file, then null bytes will be used to fill in any space between the end of the file and the file position you wrote to.

Comment: Ok, but my chunks are arrived a synchronicity. So for file of 2600KB, I can get the third part (2048KB-2600KB) first, and then the first and the second. In addition, I don't know the size of the file. Seems that it can be a problem.. I tried it now, and in the file has a lot of `nul` characters.

Comment: Right, but at some point you'll be filling in the first and second part, overwriting those null bytes. I'm not understanding why you need to know the size of the file as long as you have the offsets.

Comment: I try the following code, and for 2600KB, it gives me 800KB file, with nul characters:
`var buffer = fs.readFileSync(returnFilePath(file) + start);
                fs.open(returnFilePath(file) + "_part", 'w+',function (err, fd){
fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, start);
                    fs.closeSync(fd);
;`